# Fixing ModelBuilder error? Error 010045: COSTPATH: The number of FROM cells is 0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I'm a beginner to ModelBuilder and I keep getting the error shown below.

I keep getting the same error even when I convert point to raster:

> Error 010045: COSTPATH: The number of FROM cells is 0

[image: Model Builder Error]

[image: Attribute table]

Answer (score 2):

Try making Start_123, Output Cost Distance, and Output Backlink prerequisites to Cost Path.  What ModelBuilder is probably trying to do is run the Cost Path operation *first*, before the other bits of the model have run.  By setting all three of the inputs to prerequisites you're telling it "Don't do this until the rest of the model is done, doofus."

Also, unless they aren't ever going to change, you want to make Start_123 and finish_2t parameters, that way you don't have to open up the model every time you need to run it.